# Unable to click textarea

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, textarea

I'm working on a project that's coded in Java and I'm using Selenium to automate a process.
I have these two textareas and I've no problem at all to send my text to the first area because I can find it by `id`.

```
<td class="tdLeft">:</td>
<td class="tdRight">
<textarea placeholder="" id="add_links" name="links[]"></textarea>
</td>

driver.findElementById("add_links").sendKeys("\n");
```

But there is a second text area that I have problems with.

```
<tr>
<td class="tdLeft">:</td>
<td class="tdRight">
<textarea name="links[]"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
```

How can I get my text into this one ?

Comment: how about adding different `id` in the second text area.

Comment: or check if there is a way in selenium to get element objects with name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long way would be:

```
List<WebElement> txtAreas = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//textarea[name='links[]']"));
for (WebElement txtArea : txtAreas) { 
    if (!txtArea.getAttribute("id").equalsIgnoreCase("add_links")) {
        txtArea.sendKeys("\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

Simplest way would be:

```
WebElement txtArea = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[name='links[]' and not(@id = 'add_links')]"));
txtArea.sendKeys("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know textarea index you can try following way,

```
driver.findElementsByXPath("//textarea").get(1).sendKeys("\n");
```

Comment: Your solution is one line and worked fine.. :-) thank you

Comment: You're welcome .You are free to upvote if you really like this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 textareas with same values for `name` attribute. what you can do for second text area is as below:

```
List<WebElement> linksize=null;
 String arraylinks[]=null;
linksize = driver.findElements(By.name("links[]")); 
    int linksCount = linksize.size();
    arraylinks= new String[linksCount];
    for(int i=0;i<linksCount;i++)
    {

    arraylinks[i] = linksize.get(i).getAttribute("id");
    if(arraylinks[i].isEmpty())
    {

        System.out.println("I am second text area"+arraylinks[i]);
        linksize.get(i).sendKeys("Hello");


    }

    }
```

Here we are getting `text area` having common attributes, looping over them and sending text only to that one which do not have `id`. It is working for me. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath,`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr/td[2]/textarea[@]"))`

Comment: The given selector //tr/td[2]/textarea[@] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using `cssSelectors`:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("textarea[name='links[]']"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found doubleclick and then sendkey as solution :D

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(findElement(locator)).doubleClick().build().perform();
locator.sendKeys("Text");
```